# how can I make express render any jade file in one directory, regardless of path depth?

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I have an app with views that are in directories like so:

```
$ ftree ./web/views
| |____views
| | |____index.jade
| | |____404.jade
| | |____partials
| | | |____test.index.jade
| | | |____index.jade
| | | |____test
| | | | |____index.jade **** 
| | |____layout.jade
| | |____500.jade
```

I'd like to be able to render the view at `/views/partials/test/index.jade` when I call `/partials/test/index.jade`. I have my route set up like so:

```
exports.partials = (req, res)->
  filename = req.params.filename
  return unless filename # might want to change this
  console.log "rendering partial at #{filename}"
  res.render "partials/#{filename}"
```

and

```
app.configure(->
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001)
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')
...
app.get('/partials/:filename', routes.partials)
```

This all works fine for `partials/index.jade` and `partials/test.index.jade` but it fails (404) for `partials/test/index.jade`.

Do I have to make a route for each subdirectory of `/partials`? I'd like express to render any file under `/partials`, since there will be a few of them. I considered using the static directory instead but it looks like static files won't go through the jade processor middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

params cannot contain `/`. When evaluated the url is tokenized by `/` to get params.

When you do `app.get('/partials/:filename', routes.partials)` it matches partials/index.jade because `req.params.filename` is set to `index.jade` (only one valid params). But it does not match `partials/test/index.jade` because two params are required to match.

To achieve what you want you can do this

```
app.get('/partials/*', routes.partials)
```

and in routes do:

```
exports.partials = (req, res)->
  filename = req.params
  return unless filename # might want to change this
  console.log "rendering partial at #{filename}"
  res.render "partials/#{filename}"
```

In above code `req.params` matches everything after `/partials/` so you render the path correctly. So you can even create sub directories inside them